# How to handle a bitmask of 128 bits in C++

Tags: c++, memory

I am a complete beginner in C++, and I never used it or coded with it. But today, I have to fix a problem in C++ code. Compiling, finding the problem, and understanding the code wasn't that difficult, but fixing it is another story when you don't have any prior knowledge of C++ syntax and structure.

I have a channel selection based on a bitmask. Consider the following 5 channels example:

- `mask: 11111` -> all 5 channels are selected
- `mask: 11110` -> channels [2, 3, 4, 5] are selected
- `mask: 00110` -> channels [2, 3] are selected

This idea is used to select channels on an EEG device, which typically has a lot of channels. Thus to shorten the mask for the user, it is converted to hexadecimal.
The working example uses a 64 channel device, with a mask coded on 64 bits.

```
// EEG channels mask
tmpParam = ui.EEG_LineEdit->text();
std::string tmpString = tmpParam.toStdString();
unsigned long long hexEegMask = std::strtoull(tmpString.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
```

The hexadecimal mask is retrieved from the UI in a string and converted to an integer on 64 bits in `hexEegMask`. Then `hexEegMask` is converted to a bitset on 64 bits:

```
// convert the eeg mask to a bits array for ch labelling
std::bitset<64> hexEegMask_bits(this->hexEegMask);
```

e.g.

```
// mask in the UI to select 64 chs: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
unsigned long long hexEegMask = std::strtoull(tmpString.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
std::bitset<64> hexEegMask_bits(this->hexEegMask);
// that gives us hexEegMask_bits with 64 '1'
```

This structure works fine with a 64 channels device.. but not anymore with a 128 channels device! I'm guessing `long long long long` is not valid in C++ ^^'

How can I get this channel selection to work with 128 channels with minimal code modifications?

EDIT: I have no clue if the code snippets I provided are completely valid. If needed, I can provide perma-links to the involved lines on the GitHub repository.

EDIT2: Going with the idea to split the 32 hex digits mask into 2, I changed the code to use `unsigned long long hexEegMask1` and `unsigned long long hexEegMask2`. The channel selection is done as:

```
// retrieve hexEegMask_bits size
unsigned int size = static_cast<unsigned int>(hexEegMask1_bits.size())

std::bitset<64> hexEegMask1_bits(this->hexEegMask1);
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    if (hexEegMask1_bits[k] == 1) {
        std::string ch_name = this->capLayout.at(k);
        channels.append_child("channel")
            .append_child_value("label", ch_name)
            .append_child_value("type", "EEG")
            .append_child_value("unit", "uV");
        }
    }

std::bitset<64> hexEegMask2_bits(this->hexEegMask2);
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    if (hexEegMask2_bits[k] == 1) {
        std::string ch_name = this->capLayout.at(k + size);
        channels.append_child("channel")
            .append_child_value("label", ch_name)
            .append_child_value("type", "EEG")
            .append_child_value("unit", "uV");
        }
    }
```

But I am missing the code to split the original 32 hex digit string into 2 16 elements strings. i.e. going from `std::string tmpString = tmpParam.toStdString();` to `unsigned long long hexEegMask1` and `unsigned long long hexEegMask2`. Anyone could help me with splitting `tmpString` into 2 16 elements strings?

Comment: Would you mind sharing which medical device manufacturer or facility assigned the task of maintaining the code for a critical medical device to a C++ beginner? This is not your fault, but whoever's doing it must be named and shamed.

Comment: Why not just read the mask into two 64-bit words?

Comment: It's also not clear to me how and why writing a bitmask in hex format should be easier for a user...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ahah, thank you for your kind words, but this is for research purposes only, and the last engineer working on this didn't have time to fully wrap up the mode with more than 64 channels (which is ahead of what the device manufacturer is providing for now). 
As of now, I don't have the time to allocate to learn C++, and hopefully, my Python and general knowledge were enough to get me this far on this particular problem. But this change is above my current C++ level.

Comment: @Federico It is not simpler, it's a pain, but it's for research purposes so that's good enough and at least it fits on the screen. While 128 `1`.. ^^'

Comment: @stark Yes that sounds like a very good idea!! Could you please provide a couple of code snippets to do that, from which I can start working? As I don't know the syntax for C++, any lead and code snippet will be very helpful!

Comment: 16 hex digits is already too many for a user interface. It should at least be broken up into 4 groups of 8 hex digits separated by spaces. Start by fixing the UI, then read it into an array of appropriate unsigned ints, for example, `uint32_t  hexEegMask[4]`

Comment: Using a std::bitset could help you here.  I think a you would need to do is convert the hex string into a binary string to initialize the bitset.

Comment: @stark Yes, I agree 16 hex digits is a pain to work with. But it's doable. One day it will be fix, but for now my time is very limited and my knowledge of C++ is too limited. 'with minimal code modifications' -> the less code I have to change, the better because every change will take me a substantial amount of time, as a beginner.
With the 16 hex digit as str as is, how can I load it into 2 64 bits integers?

Comment: @NathanOliver could you provide a code snippet to do that?

Comment: You can't.  It requires 32 hex digits for 128 bits.

Comment: @stark My mistake. 16 hex digit is what I have now and that works up to 64 bits. So for 128 bits, I have a 32 hex digit mask, how can I load it into 2 pieces of 16 digit each?

Comment: I have most of the code sorted out to split the 32 hex digit mask into 2 16 hex digit mask. The only part I'm missing is how to split that 32-character string into 2 16 characters strings. `std::string tmpString = tmpParam.toStdString();` -> how can I get from `tmpString` 2 16 character strings? @stark

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited my question with the current status. If I didn't make any mistake, the only step missing is to split `tmpString` (32 element string) into 2 16 elements strings. A trivial operation in Python.. that I struggle with. Would you mind giving me a hand with this one?

Comment: Look into [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). This allows to split the string into parts.

Comment: @OlafDietsche So with `tmpString` being this 32 hex digit string, does this work?
`std:: string tmpString1 = tmpString.substr(0, 16)` and `std:: string tmpString2 = tmpString.substr(16, 16)` followed by `unsigned long long hexEegMask1 = std::strtoull(tmpString1.c_str(), nullptr, 16);` and the eq. for `tmpString2` to convert them to integers?

Comment: What you're looking for is `std::string`'s `substr()` method.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you. Are the couple of lines I wrote in the comment above correct? Thousand thanks!

Comment: Yes, this looks good. You split the string into two parts, and then convert each part to an integer.